# How to retrieve data from list<String> in Mule for-each scope?

Tags: string, list, mule

I am having some problems with iterating over a list collection in Mule, using the for-each scope. The iteration works fine, goes over every line, but I can't figure out how to extract the data I need. The revelant code part is below, 'Address' is a list, and I need to get each String from the list, which would be added to the 'finalString' variable, with some extra information.

```
<foreach collection="#[payload['Address']]" doc:name="For Each" counterVariableName="i" rootMessageVariableName="Original">
<set-variable variableName="finalString" value="#[flowVars['finalString']]" doc:name="Variable"/>
</foreach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the foreach scope, each line will be represented by `payload`.

So you could use something like:

```
<foreach collection="#[payload['Address']]" doc:name="For Each" counterVariableName="i" rootMessageVariableName="Original">
   <set-variable variableName="finalString" value="#[flowVars['finalString'] + payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
</foreach>
```

But that will look like "nulladdress1address2" but you can change this to check for null or concat differently.

Comment: Thanks for the information, just managed to solve it getting some other help. Somehow I read the documents, but could not see without some external prompting that each line is represented by payload.